# fontforge how to export/import svg file by character name or character unicode in command line

Tags: bash, command, inkscape, fontforge

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6en2.png)

like this picture,I had extract some characters' names and unicodes,and I need to modify these characters with Inkscape.Now the question is:

**in Fontforge,how to export/import svg file by character name or unicode in command line?**

for example,how can I export `A.svg` by "A" or "uni0041"?

I know how to export ALL the characters with this command:

```
fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export("svg"); endloop;' font.ttf
```

but this not suitable for my work,I need to export these characters one by one.

Comment: This is a task probably better done via python scripting.